# Using 100% does not make my canvas fill the window

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, fullscreen

I'm trying to make my canvas fill up the entire window. Setting the width and height to 100% isn't working at all. Instead, it's making it 100px by 100px. Why would this be happening, and how can I achieve my effect?

Here's a fiddle that basically shows my problem. Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/t04n6q9y/1/

```
<body height="100%" width="100%">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Please don't use CSS for that, you'll face a lot of difficulties when trying to do more than a `ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)`. eg, if you want to add some mouse listener, your coord will be messed up, if you try to draw a circle, it may end in an oval, if you try to `drawImage()` proportions will be messed up and in any case, your pixel ratio will be wrong.

Comment: Your code sets the canvas size to 100x100 px because both canvas.width & canvas.height take numeric sizes and not percentage sizes. `canvas.width=window.innerWidth;` & `canvas.height=window.innerHeight` will resize your canvas to the current window size.

Answer (score 0):

The width and height are attributes and don't support `%` they need to be absolute. If you give `100%` width and height in CSS, your canvas will not scale to `100%` instead it will be zoomed to 100%.  I would suggest the following way to achieve 100% width and height:

You need to calculate width in javascript and then apply it, [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmho040p/)

js:

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.height = height;
```

Snippet:

```js
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.height = height;
canvas.width = width;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #00000F
}
canvas {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: That's the only answer that takes into account that OP probably will do more than fillRect on the canvas

Answer (score -1):

You should be doing this with CSS rather than HTML tag attributes. By declaring a CSS class, you will be able to apply this same style to anything else you may want to fullscreen. It also separates the DOM logic from the styling logic.

Here's how I would do it:

**HTML:**

```
<canvas class="fullscreen"></canvas>
```

**CSS:**

```
canvas.fullscreen {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

The "vw" and "vh" units represent percentage of View Width and View Height, respectively. Using these units will ensure your canvas fills the entire viewport regardless of the size of its parent elements.

Answer (score -1):

All that needed to be done was for the canvas to have an element to expand in.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="canback">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #00000F
}

#canback {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}

#myCanvas {
background:#f4f4f4;
height:100%;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t04n6q9y/20/)

I hope this helped. :D

Comment: yea i just noticed i had it in there.